# file_put_contents - создает 2 одинаковых имени файла при параллельном вызове

Tags: php, файлы

Как такое возможно в принципе?
ОС не важна, на всех ОС создает (Windows, CentOS 7, Ubuntu 20.x).

В файле index.php например код:

```
file_put_contents("time47.inc", "0", LOCK_EX);
```

Понятное дело, что может одновременно несколько раз быть вызван в сессию index.php, но как такое ВОЗМОЖНО?

Почему не перезаписывается файл, или по ошибке пустым не становится - как можно получить 2 файла с одним именем и при чем оба отображаются и редактируются?

[image: double_file_name]

Comment: Проверьте свой код внимательно. Скорее всего в имени файла присутствует спецсимвол из-за которого ОС при его создании ведет себя по-разному - то удаляет его из имени файла, то преобразует в другой (или оставляет как есть) , но вывести такой символ не может. Поэтому при отображении Вы и видите два файла с одинаковыми именами. Возможно Вы также не видите этот символ при редактировании скрипта из-за кодировки в которой скрипт сохранен.

Comment: во втором файле небось `е` русская

Comment: Я четко напсиал код - код один, никаких двойственностей.
time47.inc пропсиано руками на одном языке.

Если бы там были какие-то вариации, я не задавал бы вопрос здесь, я много лет программирую, и не знаю, как можно такое сделать самому, руками, или программно.

Comment: Функция на хостинге медленная, это ясно. Выполняет три этапа fopen flock fclose.
Когда ОС получила дескриптор файла при fopen - до того как она получит flock - у меня еще раз может выполнится от другого юзера этот же код.
 
Я согласен, что в сессии возникает два разных дескриптора открытых к одному имени файла - но вот потом одна из них явно ведь получает flock, пишет и закрывает файл, а другая, как может записать в это же имя мимо этого файла?
Пусть она позже пишет, но при попытке fclose - должны же имена проверяться, как можно успешно закрыть файл когда такой же уже закрыт в каталоге?